# Why is sets not a path category

Tags: category-theory

If we let $U$ be a class and let disjont sets $Q(A,B)$ be given for each pair $(A,B)\in U^2$ then the associated path category is the category $\mathfrak{C}$ with:

$ob(\mathfrak{C})=U$ and morphisms given by sequences $(f_1,..f_n)$ where we have that $target(f_i)=source(f_{i+1})$ and composition is given by concatenation.

I want to show that the categroy $Sets$ is not a path category but I am not really sure how to proceed with this? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Hint: does a path category have (co)products?

Comment: Ok so it doesn't- is this because if we took a coproduct of $U_1$ and $U_2$ say $P$ then for any other $Q$ with $U_i\rightarrow Q$ we need a unique map $f:Q\rightarrow P$ that satisfies the commutative diagram. Now if we assume that there was such an $f$ could we just throw another map in there, say the identity map so (f,I_P). Then this would still satisfy the required commutative diagram and hence our map $f$ would not be unique?

Comment: yes, something of that sort can be turned into a precise argument.

Comment: Ok, just for me to be clear. In the path category the empty tuple of maps is the identity and so we could take $if:P\rightarrow P$ and then have the tuple $(Id_A,Id_A,...,Id_A)$ which is not equal to the identity in the path category but we could use this to show that uniqueness does not hold?